# What is the point of the end-of-round escape sequence?

Tags: titanfall-2

After a victor is declared in most multiplayer modes, a dropship comes to evacuate the losing team if they can make it there without dying and without the dropship being blown up.

What's the point of all this? It just seems to waste time after this round and before the next round begins. After my team has already won or lost, what advantage do I get by performing well in this post-round minigame thing?

Comment: In the first one, it was just there to kill time/give bragging rights. But it also awarded points for success, and those points translated to XP. I'd imagine Titanfall 2 is similar, but can't confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The epilogue of the fight really only matters for the losing team to gain a consolation prize. Where-as for the winning team, it's similar to the *Team Fortress 2* humiliation period at the end of a round.

During the Epilogue, the evacuating team have an attempt to earn an additional **Merit** (EXP for Titanfall 2) if they manage to make it back onto the drop-ship and survive the encounter. Everyone at this point cannot respawn anymore, so any attempt to pick off the "victors" of the match will help improve the chances of a successful evacuation. (ie, If the enemy team has less high powered weapons, they'll very likely be unable to destory the drop-ship.)

On the other side though, it does not seem the winning team has much else to gain from preventing the evacuating team from escaping. From experience, it seems that kills during this round will still count towards one's progression, but I have not noticed any merit points for a team kill or drop-ship destruction.

Comment: Victors get a merit for winning, so I imagine the merit for evac is a way to make it "even".

Comment: So as a victor, I gain nothing from killing the losing team during the Epilogue other than denying them merit? That sounds...unsportsmanlike.

Comment: True, but it's not like they're not shooting back as well. :)